# How to select only armstrong numbers from the list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want is to select Armstrong numbers from the list below list I have searched of solution of this question bu unable to find in SQL-Server:

```
Numbers
121
113
423
153
541
371
```

I am sure most of you know what's the Armstrong number and how to calculate though I am describing is for the simplicity : sum of the cubes of its digits is equal to the number itself i.e.

```
1*1*1 + 5*5*5 + 3*3*3 = 153
3*3*3 + 7*7*7 + 1*1*1 = 371
```

Please help me on this as I am also trying but seeking for quick solution. It will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I have to perform different operations on that column's values so I don't statically maintain it, Anyways thanks.

Comment: Why are you bringing a knife to a gun fight? Use practically any modern application language to do the job rather than stretching a 40-year old dinosaur language (aka SQL) to do something it wasn't designed for. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Can you get a list from someplace like OEIS and do a join?

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestion and help. I found so many helpful answers below but I wanted to do it without using UDF and I got that also Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to find Armstrong numbers using Sql functions:

```
WITH Numbers AS(
SELECT 0 AS number UNION ALL SELECT number + 1 FROM  Numbers  WHERE number < 10000)
SELECT number AS ArmstrongNumber FROM Numbers
WHERE
    number = POWER(COALESCE(SUBSTRING(CAST(number AS VARCHAR(10)),1,1),0),3)
           + POWER(COALESCE(SUBSTRING(CAST(number AS VARCHAR(10)),2,1),0),3)
           + POWER(COALESCE(SUBSTRING(CAST(number AS VARCHAR(10)),3,1),0),3)  
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick mod to my sum of digits UDF

```
Declare @Table table (Numbers int)
Insert into @Table values
(121),
(113),
(423),
(153),
(541),
(371)

Select * from @Table where [dbo].[udf-Stat-Is-Armstrong](Numbers)=1
```

Returns

```
Numbers
153
371
```

The UDF

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Stat-Is-Armstrong](@Val bigint)
Returns Bit
As
Begin

Declare @RetVal as bigint
Declare @LenInp as bigint = len(cast(@Val as varchar(25)))
;with i AS (
    Select @Val / 10 n, @Val % 10 d
    Union ALL
    Select n / 10, n % 10
    From i
    Where n > 0
)
Select @RetVal = IIF(SUM(power(d,@LenInp))=@Val,1,0) FROM i;
Return @RetVal
End
```

Comment: thanks for quick solution, I am again looking after to do it using query without any function.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  153 x into #temp;
insert #temp values(371);
insert #temp values(541);

with cte as (select x, substring(cast(x as nvarchar(40)) ,1,1) as u, 1 as N FROM #temp
            union all
            select x, substring(cast(x as nvarchar(40)),n+1,1) as u , n+1 from cte where len(cast(x as nvarchar(40))) > n
            )

    select x from cte group by x having SUM(POWER(cast(u as int),3)) = x


drop table #temp;
```

here is the mark 2 - you can change the @ORDER to explore power of 4,5 etc

```
declare @order int = 3;
declare @limit int = 50000;

with        nos as (select 1 no 
            union all 
            select no + 1 from nos where no < @limit),          
            cte as (select no as x, substring(cast(no as nvarchar(40)) ,1,1) as u, 1 as N FROM nos
            union all
            select x, substring(cast(x as nvarchar(40)),n+1,1) as u , n+1 from cte where len(cast(x as nvarchar(40))) > n
            )

    select x from cte group by x having SUM(POWER(cast(u as int),@order)) = x
    option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously static processing during each query is not correct approach but we can create function like this and

```
create function dbo.IsArmstrongNumber(@n int)
returns int as 
begin 
    declare @retValue int = 0
    declare @sum int = 0
    declare @num int = @n
    while @num > 0
    begin
        set @sum += (@num%10) * (@num%10) * (@num%10)
        set @num = @num/10
    end 
    IF @sum = @n
        set @retValue = 1
    return @retValue
end
```

Pre-processing and selecting in IN clause is better

```
select * from #Numbers where dbo.IsArmstrongNumber(n) = 1
```