# Check for Armstrong Numbers using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query in Oracle SQL that checks if a number is Armstrong or not.

Most of the queries in internet sources are in PL/SQL but I just need it in Oracle SQL.

Comment: I'd guess a recursive cte can do it.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And also describe the armstrong numbers.

Comment: It would be helpful to specify what an "Armstrong number" is.  I'm guessing you want this definition https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-armstrong-numbers/ but you would know for sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474555/how-to-select-only-armstrong-numbers-from-the-list

Comment: Repeating the same text to bypass the minimum text length requirement is a violation of the site guidelines. Also, your post title is useless - it simply repeats the tags and adds the word *task*. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to recurse over the digits of each number and sum the cube of the digits to find the matching numbers:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( value, pos, total ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         POWER(SUBSTR(value, 1, 1), LENGTH(value))
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  POWER(SUBSTR(value, 1, 1), LENGTH(value)) <= value
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         pos + 1,
         total + POWER(SUBSTR(value, pos + 1, 1), LENGTH(value))
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  pos < LENGTH(value)
  AND    total + POWER(SUBSTR(value, pos + 1, 1), LENGTH(value)) <= value
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET order_id
SELECT value
FROM   rsqfc
WHERE  pos = LENGTH(value)
AND    total = value;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 400;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 153 |
| 370 |
| 371 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yoyed-JJ)